# using std::tr1::shared_ptr as an internal mechanism for reference counting

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, tr1, reference-counting

Is it safe and correct to use an std::tr1::shared_ptr as in the sample code below, for the purpose of reference counting? (this is just a particular sample, the class can contain anything else (void*) instead of the FILE*)

```
class File
{
public:
    File(const char* path, const char* mode) :
        _refcount(new int(0))
    {
        this->_file = fopen(path, mode);
    }

    ~File()
    {
        if (this->_refcount.unique())
        {
            if (this->_file != NULL)
            {
                fclose(this->_file);
            }
        }
    }

    int write(void* buff, size_t size)
    {
        fwrite(buff, size, 1, this->_file);
    }

private:
    FILE* _file;
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<int> _refcount;
};
```

Comment: Safe in what sense? Memory safe? Thread safe?

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, memory safe and thread safe, and from any other points of view. (I suppose that it is not thread safe, maybe you can explain how it can be fixed)

Comment: I didn't say it isn't thread-safe ;) But I'd write this like James's solution rather than an explicit ref-counter.

Comment: At first glance, I don't see any obvious data races in your example.  If `unique()` returns true, then the only instance owning the `FILE*` is the one being destroyed, so there are no other instances to be copied, so there is no way for `unique()` to cease to be true again.  Of course, performing I/O through a single `FILE*` from multiple threads can only end in tears. /cc @KennyTM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider instead using a `shared_ptr<FILE>` with a custom deleter:

```
struct fclose_deleter
{
    void operator()(FILE* f)
    {
        if (f)
        {
            std::fclose(f);
        }
    }
};
```

Then, your `File` class is much simpler (and correcter):

```
class File
{
public:
    File(const char* path, const char* mode)
        : _file(std::fopen(path, mode), fclose_deleter())
    {
    }

    int write(void const* buff, size_t size)
    {
        // You'll want to verify that _file.get() is valid, or you'll want to
        // throw in the constructor if the call to 'std::fopen()' fails.
        std::fwrite(buff, size, 1, _file.get());
    }

private:
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<FILE> _file;
};
```

Comment: the class can contain any data (void*), the file is just an example

Comment: This technique applies to any sort of reference-counted object that requires cleanup.

Comment: This and other interesting `shared_ptr` techniques can be found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html :)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis There are two downsides to this approach: 1. everywhere in the class I will have to use _file.get(); 2. I have to create other shared_ptr, if the class has more pointer members. Can you point any advantages over my original version?

Comment: Why do you have to create another `shared_ptr`?  Create a private `Context` type that has all of your "shared" members.  As for having to use `_file.get()`, if that _really_ bothers you, add a `FILE* file() const { return _file.get(); }`.  As for advantages, yes:  it is simpler, easier to understand with respect to ownership and resource management, and much harder to screw up.